# Vb.net Model View Control

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

Does anyone have a good website for the basics of using Model View Control pattern with either vb.net or C#. Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Asp.Net MVC technology (which uses the MVC pattern of course) or are you referring to the general design pattern of MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/

has extensive examples in both vb and c#

The [NerdDinner project](http://www.nerddinner.com/) has a free 185 page walkthrough describing how to build the NerdDinner website from scratch at http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html.  This one is c# only.